# Documentation for TRegex flavor

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-xe

Delphi XE implementation for Regex (TRegex) has significant differences. Where can I find a list of the available syntax? I've looked into Regexbuddy and RegexMagic but I can't believe there is no official documentation. I'm struggling with basic stuff to work, like matching a substring at the beginning of the string.

Comment: "Significant differences" from *what*? It's based on PCRE, and the documentation for the support can be found at any site that has PCRE documentation, including [Regular-Expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info), which has the freeware implementation that forms the basis of Delphi's implementation.

Comment: I should also mention that the author of Regular-Expressions.info is Jan Goyvaerts, who is also the author of TPerlRegEx (the basis of Delphi's implementation), RegexBuddy, and RegexMagic. (RegexBuddy will even generate the Delphi code for you to use.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Embarcadero documentation for [`TRegEx`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx) say the following:

> TRegEx calls the TPerlRegEx functions that interface with the open source PCRE library.

So the regex flavour is PCRE. The Embarcadero documentation also gives a link to off-site documentation: http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html

Perhaps the best place to start for documentation of the Delphi wrappers is also on that site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html